# What are some reason to use Hosting Type: Forwarding?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hosting

**(Please don't bash me for not understanding. This is why I am asking.)**

I am setting up a subdomain on 1and1 to place my images into it. I noticed that there are 3 option for "Hosting Type" listed:

> Website Hosting,  Forwarding,  No Website Hosting

*I am selecting to use Website Hosting because I am still hosting the images correct?*

**Forwarding:**

I looked further into this and could find answers in the documentation about 301 and 302 redirects in order to keep your indexing. There was another reason given for *"frame forwarding"* where users are redirected to another site, and the address bar of their browsers continues to show the source URL.

*Are there other applications than this?*

**No Website Hosting:**

You can switch off web service and use only email services under that domain.

*So This could be used to set up a mail server correct? Are there any other applications?*

Comment: if you got access SSH you can sudo a2dissite website
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload, if you dont want apache you can remove it too : sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 ...

Comment: Do you mean to use a2dissite to to remove apache and set up Nginx to host static data like images.. Is that correct?

Comment: Mail server isn't the same services or protocoles but if you need to install a web hosting mailer and the client need to connect to a web interface as phpmailer or zimbra ... you need it. If the client use only protocole pop3, smtp ... isn't a problem.

Comment: I setup phpMailer in the past and I couldn't figure out why I was having an issue. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome good luck ;).

Comment: Thanks for respecting my desire to learn and not putting me down for not knowing! :)